# Number of values of $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^2+n+2$ is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

My approach:

**Case $1$:** $n$ is positive:

Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $$n^2+n+2=x^2$$
$$\implies n+2=x^2-n^2=(x+n)(x-n)$$

$$\therefore x-n=\frac{n+2}{x+n}$$ $\because x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $$n+2\ge x+n$$$$\implies x\le 2$$ $$\therefore x^2 \le 4$$

**Case $2$:** $n$ is negative:
Let $n=-k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\therefore 2-k=x^2-k^2=(x+k)(x-k)$$
$$\therefore x+k=\frac{2-k}{x-k}$$

$\because x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $$2-k\ge x-k$$$$\implies x\le 2$$ $$\therefore x^2 \le 4$$

In both cases, $x^2\le 4$, so the only possible values of $n^2+n+2$ as a perfect square are ${1,4}$.

If $x^2=1$ $$n^2+n=-1$$ which has no real solutions.

If $x^2=4$ $$n^2+n=2$$ $$n=1,-2$$

So the answer is $2$

**Is my approach correct? If yes, can someone show me shorter or more elegant methods to solve this?**

Comment: FYI, see [Integral value of $n$ that makes $n^2+n+1$ a perfect square.](/q/1857258/602049) and [Find all positive integers $n$ such that $n^2+n+43$ becomes a perfect square](/q/1783946) (found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%5E2%2Bn%2B2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aperfect%20square&p=1)).

Comment: If you set $n^2+n+2-x^2=0$ and use the quadratic formula, you discover $4x^2-7=(2x)^2-7$ must be a perfect square. This is only satisfied by $x=2$ (I leave that demonstration to you). Plugging that value of $x$ back into the first quadratic formula, you get $n=\frac{-1\pm 3}{2}$ Yielding the $-2,1$ you found.

Comment: P.S: I forgot to write $0$ as another possible solution, although for no real values of $n$ does the given expression evaluate into $0$, so the answer is still $2$.

Comment: @KeithBackman thanks! Even I had tried to determine something from the quadratic formula, but the fact that $4x^2-7$ is a perfect square passed over my head!